# Error: Cannot convert 'const value_type' to 'char'

Tags: c++, vector

```
firstChar = infix[i];
```

`firstChar` is a char, and `infix` is a string vector. Trying to store the char from vector[i] in `firstChar`, but it's not going so well.

There's also two other errors if you'd like to help out on those.

error: could not convert 'firstChar' from 'char' to 'std::__cxx11::string'

```
precedenceHolder = precedence(firstChar);
```

On this one, I've tried static casting the firstChar to a string, but that just caused a whole lot of other errors.

error: could not convert 's.LinkedStack::peek,char.()' from 'char' to 'std::__cxx11::string'

```
while (!s.isEmpty() && s.peek() != '(' && precedenceHolder <= precedence(s.peek()))
```

Thanks for any help. I'm expecting to bomb this project.

Edit: variable names are as follows

```
LinkedStack<char> s;
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
char firstChar;
vector<string> postFix;
int precedenceHolder;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as string vector, probably you mean a vector of strings. Please provide the types of the variables as they appear in the code to avoid ambiguity and confusions.

Comment: Alright I added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the command

```
firstChar = infix[i];
```

`firstChar` is of type `char`, while `infix[i]` is the i-th `string`. You can't assign a `string` to a `char`, but you can retrieve the first `char` from the `string`:

```
firstChar = infix[i][0];
```

Comment: I don't really understand how that works, but it fixed that one lol thank you

Comment: @Sam: what is there to not understand? `infix` is a `std::vector` of `std::string` elements. `std::vector` has an `operator[]` to access a specific element in the array. `std::string` has its own `operator[]` to access a specific character in the string. `firstChar = infix[i][0]` is equivalent to doing this: `string &s = infix[i]; firstChar = s[0];` (what it is actually doing is this: `firstChar = infix.operator[](i).operator[](0);`)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I just didn't know that you could do `infix[i][0]` nor how it worked.